# Linphone's Compiled EXE can not run

Tags: compilation, makefile, voip, linphone

I am a newbie in linphone compilation and I am trying to compile it on my Ubuntu system.

Configuration:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Linphone version: 3.9.1
- Inno compiler setup using wine

I have followed all the steps mentioned in README file of Linphone and followed below steps.

- Install dependencies libtool, inittool, etc.
- Clone belle-sip and followed it's README.
- Installed dependencies pkg-config, libantlr3c-3.2, antlr3, bctoolbox (using clone and cmake), gcc, cunit.
- Other debian / ubuntu dependencies from README such as libcunit1-dev, libpolarssl-dev, make, libgtk2.0-dev, libspeexdsp-dev, libavcodec-dev, libswscale-dev, libx11-dev, libxv-dev, libgl1-mesa-dev, libglew1.6-dev, libv4l-dev, libxml2-dev, libreadline-dev, libgsm1-dev, libtheora-dev, libsqlite3-dev, libupnp4-dev, libsrtp-dev
- compile using ./autogen.sh, ./configure, make, make install, make zip, make setup.exe

All above command run successfully and generate output file successfully like Makefile, .zip file, .exe file. 
when I am trying to install generated .exe (Size 22 MB) in any windows system, it install successfully but Linphone.exe file not generated during installation

It gives an error "Unable to execute file" (attached error screenshot).

[image: Linphone.exe not found]

Output of command "make setup.exe" is [here](http://pastebin.com/6vnPUPW0)
I am very grateful if anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please help me if anybody have a single clue on this. I am really stuck here. Your help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but : the file added to the installer is named `bin/linphone`, not `bin\linphone.exe` according to the logfile. Looks like an oversight, as Windows uses extensions to indicate executable files whereas Linux uses the +x bits.